# UITableView asks for a cell that is not visible on screen

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I have a UITableView which I fill with data coming in from a web service. I use a circular buffer to cache fresh data and remove old, so the memory does not get overloaded.
All the magic happens when the table view calls cellForRowAtIndexPath and the view controller consults the buffer to get the data. Also, correct implementation relies on the fact that table view will only call that method when a cell will become visible on screen. If the data is available, I return it to the view controller, if not, I return nil, which view controller knows how to handle, and start fetching the data that is needed. Once the fetch is completed, I call 'reloadData' on the table, and the data appears.

I have a strange issue, out of nowhere, even if user scrolled to 200th row, table view asks the view controller for the row at index path zero or one. At that point, what gets shown, is wrong, given the buffer implementation & size.

Just to illustrate, with debugger output, from inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath :

```
 po indexPath <NSIndexPath: 0xb02b100> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}

 po [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] <__NSArrayM 0x9b8f7f0>( <NSIndexPath: 0x9b42910> {length = 2, path = 0 - 19}, <NSIndexPath: 0x9b82080> {length = 2, path = 0 - 20}, <NSIndexPath: 0x9b6e2a0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 21}, <NSIndexPath: 0x9b39010> {length = 2, path = 0 - 22}, <NSIndexPath: 0x9b42d80> {length = 2, path = 0 - 23}, <NSIndexPath: 0x9b98a20> {length = 2, path = 0 - 24}, <NSIndexPath: 0x9b9dc50> {length = 2, path = 0 - 25}, <NSIndexPath: 0x9b9e4d0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 26}, <NSIndexPath: 0x9b40740> {length = 2, path = 0 - 27}, <NSIndexPath: 0x9b40750> {length = 2, path = 0 - 28}, <NSIndexPath: 0x9b88150> {length = 2, path = 0 - 29}, <NSIndexPath: 0x9b88160> {length = 2, path = 0 - 30}, <NSIndexPath: 0x9b97120> {length = 2, path = 0 - 31}, <NSIndexPath: 0x9b97130> {length = 2, path = 0 - 32}, <NSIndexPath: 0x9b44cf0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 33}, <NSIndexPath: 0x9b44d00> {length = 2, path = 0 - 34}, <NSIndexPath: 0x9b8d580> {length = 2, path = 0 - 35}, <NSIndexPath: 0x9b8d590> {length = 2, path = 0 - 36} )
```

Has anyone ever encountered such weird issue ?

Answer (score 0):

A table view's cellForRowAtIndexPath: isn't called to only grab cells that need to be visible; the table view usually grabs a couple of extra cells so they're ready for when the user scrolls.

To convince yourself, log the return value for cellForRowAtIndexPath:. If 6 cells are visible, I bet cellForRowAtIndexPath: was called more than 6 times.

Comment: I dont understand why would it be called more than 6 times? willShowCellAtIndexPath also logs showing indexPath with row 0.

Comment: The table view framework is buffering its table cells. As for why the table view requests row 0 when you're at the bottom of the table, I can't give a definitive answer.